# error while launching men of war assault squad

Tags: men-of-war

I'm using Windows 7 ultimate 32 bit with 1gb RAM and 512mb graphics card. I have Intel Pentium D CPU 2.80GHz and 2.80GHz.

I have recently installed men of war assault squad in my PC.
 When I try to open the game it shows an error:

```
Program will be terminated.
eip=00590deb EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION read at 0×00000000
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00a7e663
edx=0000050a
esi=00000000 edi=00d34084 esp=0012fa74
ebp=00c1b628
>>main
>screen:set_mode
```

*Men of war Assault squad editor-v1.80.1-editor
2011.01.25 16:33-0×008E1057*

Even when I try to open the game the same happens.

Comment: "I have tried to open it with xp service pack 3 compatibility but it didn't work." –OP

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this game doesn't like DirectX11.

> Well I finally fixed the problem, by **forcing the game to "XP Service Pack 3" compatibility**. I'm suspecting that it used to decide suddenly to use DirectX11 and that now it use DirectX 9 with my solution... ***–access violation screen:set_mode*** –[1cpublishing.eu](http://forum.1cpublishing.eu/showthread.php?t=15138)

You might also want to [try the patch](http://forum.1cpublishing.eu/showthread.php?t=14661) (upgrades version 1.11.3 to 1.17.5).